# Use Oracle Managed and Unmanaged providers for .net in same project

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have a solution that uses an Oracle database using traditional SQLCommand objects for queries. I've recently added a project that contains an entity framework context for the same database.

When I add both connection strings to a parent project however, I get the error `Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.`

If either string is removed, the error goes away, though obiviously I've lost the functionality I was going for. Both data access methodologies work independently, but don't seem to work together.

Here are the connection strings:

```
    <add name="HRMSAppDb" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" 
     connectionString="User Id=UserName;Password=Password;Data Source=server/service;Connection Timeout=30;"/>
    <add name="HRMSDB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HRMSDB.csdl|res://*/HRMSDB.ssdl|res://*/HRMSDB.msl;
     provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
     provider connection string=&quot;CONNECTION TIMEOUT=30;DATA SOURCE=server/service;PASSWORD=password;USER ID=username&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

So, how can I include and use both EF managed connections and unmanaged SQLCommand connection providers in the same project?

Comment: have you tried _context.Database.SqlQuery?  I can provide a sample if this works within your EF version

Comment: Indeed it seems like you might have to choose one or the other.  Do you have the need for both?

Comment: @kevinsky, I'm not fammillar with that approach; we're just using LINQ expressions to query the context, and invoke a few sprocs. Are you thinking that by replacing our query/invocation code, that we might side-step this issue? an example woudl be great. Thanks!

Comment: @iCode, Thanks for the reply; unfourtunately we were given a very large cumbersome codebase that was developed by a huge number of disconnected contractors over the course of 5 years. We just need to add a little functionality to make it work at our organization, but we don't have code to half the service stack, and queries in their model are cumbersome to say the least. Time to delivery is our most important emphasis at the moment, so yes, using a more automatic data access methodology that we can plugin anywhere in the stack without a bunch of infrastructure code is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use EF and raw sql where EF will not do an efficient job with this MVVM type architecture

1) snippet of [raw sql using EF provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx)

```
            results =
                "select o.id,CAST(1 AS NUMBER(1))AS CONTACT_TYPE, O.NAME AS ENG_NAME,CAST(0 AS NUMBER(1))  AS SPECIAL_NEEDS, " +
                myModel.StageId + " AS STAGE_ID " +
                "from organization o, contact c " +
                " where o.id = c.id " +
                " and c.disabled = 0 and c.dirty = 0 " +
                " AND utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity (UPPER('" + myModel.EngName + "'), UPPER (o.NAME)) >  " +
                JaroWinklerDistance +
                " ORDER BY utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity (UPPER('" + myModel.EngName +
                "'), UPPER (o.NAME)) DESC";


        var data = _context.Database.SqlQuery<CONTACT_DETAILS>(results);
```

2) our connection string

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="XXXEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.XXX.XXXModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.XXX.XXXModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.XXX.XXXModel.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=XXX;PASSWORD=XXX;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=XXXX;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So the key takaway here is that by using Database.SqlQuery(), we can bypass the need for the managed client runtime? is that correct?

Comment: @FrankThomas  yes, that's right.  Any legacy sql code including procedure calls can be used inside EF.

Comment: Thanks to your post, we now understand that the ODP unmanaged client will run our EF context correctly, and we didn;t even have to replace our Linq queries. Thanks for your help!